# Django Rest Framework List of Strings Serializer

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models created in my Django app and am looking for a serialization approach so that the IPs are shown in JSON as a list of strings instead of a list of IPAddress objects.

**Desired JSON**

```
[
    {
        "hostname": "www.example.com",
        "ip_addresses": [ "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ]
    }
]
```

**Current JSON**

```
[
    {
        "hostname": "www.example.com",
        "ip_addresses": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "ip_address": "1.1.1.1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "ip_address": "2.2.2.2"
            }
        ]
]
```

**urls.py**

```
class HostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hostname = serializers.CharField(source='name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Host
        fields = ['hostname', 'ip_addresses']
        depth = 1
```

**models.py**

```
class IPAddress(models.Model):
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ip_address)

class Host(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ip_addresses = models.ManyToManyField(IPAddress)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this !

```
class HostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    hostname = serializers.CharField(source='name', read_only=True)
    ip_addresses = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_ip_addresses(self, instance):
        return [item.ip_address for item in instance.ip_addresses.all()]
```

Comment: You don't need to add `read_only=True` to `SerializerMethodField` since it is already read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` to achieve what you want:

```
class HostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hostname = serializers.CharField(source='name', read_only=True)
    ip_addresses: serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Host
        fields = ['hostname', 'ip_addresses']
        depth = 1

    def get_ip_addresses(self, instance):
        return [item.ip_address for item in instance.ip_addresses]
```

Comment: Hmm still getting the same JSON response

Comment: @kernelpanic Looks like I forgot to add `all()` to get `instance.ip_addresses` :)